# Make flexbox items the same height

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm learning how to use Flexbox, and I can't get my boxes to do what I want. I want:

- Four boxes in a row, with a small gap in between them
- Each box should be the exact same size
- The text inside the box should be centered horizontally and vertically, with lots of padding
- Each box should be a link, and the entire box should be clickable; not just the text

The main problem I'm facing is that the boxes are not the same size when one has more text than the rest. This is happening despite the parent element having the align-items: stretch attribute, which I thought was supposed to correct that.

Thanks for any help. Here is my code:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    
    .parent {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: stretch;
        gap: 5px;
    }
    
    .parent li {
        list-style: none;
        background: silver;
        padding: 100px 10px;
        text-align: center;
        flex: 1 0 25%;
        margin: auto;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .parent li a {
        margin: auto;
        padding: 100px 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000000;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="parent">
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">This is box number three, and it has a lot more content than the others.</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You added the padding, to center the text right?

Comment: The reason I added 100px of vertical padding was to make the entire box clickable.

Comment: I think I got what you needed/wanted, it was complicated tbh

Comment: Thanks! But now the padding is gone. This was an exaggerated example; in my real project, the boxes would each have two or three words in them, and some of the words are longer than others, which would cause the boxes to be different heights. But I still want each box to be approximately square, with lots of vertical padding around the text.

Comment: Without that, it would completely change everything, and I don't really understand why. But it gave me a headache to finally get into an answer, so yah. Sorry if it's not the best xd

Answer (score 1):

I added random text there, to make sure it would increase the height, and still center to the text.

So basically, what I did, was use what you did and another flexbox on the `a` tag, to make it center no matter the height.

```css
body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    
    .parent {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        gap: 5px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: stretch;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    
    .parent li {
        list-style: none;
        background: silver;
        padding: 100px 10px;
        text-align: center;
        flex: 1;
        margin: auto;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 5px;
    }
    
    .parent li a {
        margin: auto;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000000;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="parent">
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">This is box number three, and it has a sjdsddsd lot more content thddd dsdssdd dssd sdsdsddddddan the others.</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```